# How to prevent a doc moving to bottom of my collection when using update

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I update a doc and then it appers on bottom in my collection. How to prevent moving my documents?

```
 try {
        await Card.update({_id: fixedUrl}, {$push:{'comments': data}})
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is - you can't prevent it.

If the document size exceeds the allocated space for that document, MongoDB will relocate the document on disk (in other words your document will be added into end of the collection file).

You can use a sorting for that (it will be pretty fast operation if you will use an index for sorting). (-;